# Combinations of sets' elements (excluding one set)

Tags: c, matrix, set, combinations

Let's say I have four sets:

```
set1 = {A, a}
set2 = {B, b}
set3 = {C, c}
set4 = {D, d}
```

Now I need all the unique combinations of their elements (doesn't matter in which order), but excluding one of the sets. For instance, not considering *set4*, I need these combinations:

```
ABC
AbC
ABc
Abc
aBC
abC
aBc
abc
```

I've tried to arrange the sets as a matrix:

```
char matrix_calc[2][4] = {
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'},
        {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
};
```

And I wrote this code in order to find the combinations:

```
uint8_t excluded = 3; // index of the column which has to be excluded

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (i != excluded) {
        for (x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j < 4; j++) {
                if (j != excluded) {
                    for (t = 0; t < 2; t++) {
                        for (k = j + 1; k < 4; k++) {
                            if (k != excluded) {
                                for (z = 0; z < 2; z++) {
                                    printf("%c %c %c\n",
                                        matrix_calc[x][i],
                                        matrix_calc[t][j],
                                        matrix_calc[z][k]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code works, but it is not flexible and it seems to be expensive (in terms of speed). For instance, if the number of sets increases, I have to change the code a lot (and I will lose myself in the additional *for loops*).

If for example I have 5 sets instead of 4, I have the following code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (i != excluded) {
        for (x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
            for (j = i + 1; j < 5; j++) {
                if (j != excluded) {
                    for (t = 0; t < 2; t++) {
                        for (k = j + 1; k < 5; k++) {
                            if (k != excluded) {
                                for (z = 0; z < 2; z++) {
                                    for (m = k + 1; m < 5; m++) {
                                        if (m != excluded) {
                                            for (w = 0; w < 2; w++) {
                                                printf("%c %c %c %c\n",
                                                        matrix_calc[x][i],
                                                        matrix_calc[t][j],
                                                        matrix_calc[z][k],
                                                        matrix_calc[w][m]);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient (and clean) way?

Comment: That might be better suited for codereview. Also thats quite a lot of `for` you got going on there.

Comment: Read here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-possible-combinations-of-r-elements-in-a-given-array-of-size-n/

Comment: What you have is a `permutation` problem. There are several smaller algorithms well suiting to those semi-statistical undertakings with several good examples on site I believe..